# RobotFrameWork: How to check an dynamic element in the top row of a component block

Tags: robotframework

So there's a website: 
https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market

And the website has a block with an ID: called   components_block

That block has rows...

how can I check that in the column of 'Chg.%' the element has a + sign in front of the value/digits.

I figured out it's the 2nd TR and then the 6th class....

so how do I do that?

I tried this:

```
Should Match Regexp  bold pidExt-23176-pcp greenFont  ^[+]
```

(however I don't like that solution, because the class name can change)

By the way, the result of the test says: does not match
while when I test the regulard expression at  https://pythex.org/ it works just fine.

so what does not match? is the class not found, or is the result of the regex not okay?

I found something that comes close(r)?:
http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-robot-framework-menu/selenium-robot-framework-python-menu/204-selenium-robot-framework-table-verification

```
Table Cell Should Contain    xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    1 1
```

Comment: This won't do - please a) add the html of the element that's interesting to you, and mostly b) show some effort on your side - what have you tried, and where do you face problems. The SO community will gladly help, but hardly do everything instead of you. If in doubt, please see here - [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`Should Match Regexp` works by checking that a string matches a given regexp - you have to first get the text of the element, and then use this keyword:

```
${the text}=    Get Text    your_locator
Should Match Regexp    ${the text}    ^[+]
```

The regexp approach is quite good; you could also use a keyword from the BuiltIn library, that in this case will verify the same:

```
Should Start With    ${the text}    +
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for you. My solution below will store all the '+' output into a list. The complete steps are:

1.Find the xpath locator for the 6th column (Chg.%). Then, find how many rows of them. 10 rows are found when I check. See code below. Note how I use this keyword: `GET ELEMENT COUNT`

```
${xpath}=   Set Variable /html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr//td[6]
${rows_found}=  Get Element Count   xpath=${xpath}
```

2.Create an empty list by using keyword: `CREATE LIST`

```
${res_list}=    Create List
```

2.Use FOR-IN RANGE loop to iterate over this 10 rows, and only store the result into the list if it has '+' text/character. When I use `GET TEXT` keyword, I pass the tr[${row}] in xpath during each iteration. Note how I use these keywords: `RUN KEYWORD AND RETURN STATUS`, `SHOULD START WITH`, `APPEND TO LIST`.

```
: FOR ${row} IN RANGE 1  ${rows_found}+1
     ${row_text}=   Get Text    xpath=/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[${row}]/td[6]
     ${text_contains_plus}= Run Keyword and Return Status   Should Start With   ${row_text} +
     Run Keyword If  '${text_contains_plus}' == 'True'  Append To List  ${res_list} ${row_text}

Log To Console  ${res_list}
Log ${res_list}
```

However, if you need to store two(2) variables, the company name that has the '+' in 6th column and it's text value (eg: +20.11), then you need to add several more lines in my script above, but the most elegant way is to use the DICTIONARY keywords in ROBOT Framework. Refer to this link: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html