# Testing data from two different source in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I want to test & validate the data from two different sources at the same time using robot framework. 
[image: Source-1]
[image: Source-2]

I'm stuck & I don't know how to proceed further. I've come up with code as far now

```
    ${row_count}=  get element count  ${basic_info_table_row}
    Should Be Equal As Integers  ${row_count}  12
    ${column_count}=  get element count  ${basic_info_table_column}
    Should Be Equal As Integers  ${column_count}  2

    ${row_list}=  BuiltIn.Create Dictionary
    FOR  ${row}  IN RANGE  ${row_count}+1
       ${row_text}  get text  ${basic_info_table_row}
       log to console  ${row_text}
    END
```

Right now what happening is, it just taking the first row and just logging the the first row again & again. [image: Report]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a loop with `FOR  ${row}  IN RANGE  ${row_count}+1` but you aren't using `${row}` anywhere *inside* the loop. The two values in that block `${row_text}` & `${basic_info_table_row}` will remain the same each time.

If you wanted to use `$row` as an index, then use that with `${basic_info_table_row}`. Or use `$row` in the xpath or whichever identifier is used for `${basic_info_table_row}` (or just `${basic_info_table}`) - that's not in your question.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642758/1431750) for how you can use an index in your identifier. Note the `tr[${row}]` used in the xpath:

```
${row_text}=   Get Text    xpath=/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[${row}]/td[6]
```

Comment: Went with the solution that you shared and it didn't workout as well. Now robot is not able to find the element as robot is indexing it from 0 [link] (https://ibb.co/F5Z0S65) [link] (https://ibb.co/4NZdpQ8)